# Gauss' original proof of quadratic reciprocity

Tags: reference-request, quadratic-reciprocity

Is the original proof of quadratic reciprocity due to Gauss available anywhere online? I've been looking for quite a while now, but with no results. Most papers seem not to include it because of it being "ugly" and "messy", though I am interested in seeing it, mainly to see how the proof by induction possibly proceeds (after all, this is a statement about primes, and they are pretty "holey').

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is his original proof. You can find it in [this](http://bookzz.org/book/690126/186dbc) translated version of Gauss' book, starts at p. 82, article 125.

I haven't read it. Just trying to help.